# Infinte loop when i run socket.io in node.js and socket.io-client in react.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sockets, socket.io

This is one of the components I wrote in Reactjs, when I run it, it gives me the following error every second:
polling-xhr.js:268 GET http://hlocalhost:4002/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N7zlNbY net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import queryString from 'query-string';
import io from "socket.io-client";

let socket;

const Chat = ({location}) => {
    const [name, setName]=useState('');
    const [room,setRoom]=useState('');
    const ENDPOINT='hlocalhost:4002';

    useEffect(()=>{
        const {name,room}=queryString.parse(window.location.search);
        socket=io(ENDPOINT);

        setName(name);
        setRoom(room);

        console.log(socket);
    },[ENDPOINT, window.location.search]);
    return(
        <h1>Chat</h1>
        )
}

export default Chat;
```

Part of node.js code

```
const http=require('http');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const bcrypt=require('bcrypt-nodejs');
const socketio=require('socket.io');
const cors=require('cors');
const PORT =process.env.PORT || 4002;

const router=require('./router');

const app=express();
const server=http.createServer(app);
const io=socketio(server);

io.on('connect',(socket)=>{
    console.log('We have a new connection!!!');
    socket.on('disconnect',()=>{
        console.log('User had left!!!');
    })
});

app.use(cors());
```

Comment: You need to pass an actual URL to `io()`, not just a host name.

Answer (score 1):

try to use cors before server initialization,you're using it in last, and once again check if url is not correct, should be in format "http://localhost:8080"

Comment: I allow the cors on the top of the file assigning URL is "http://127.0.0.1:8000". I am facing the same error i.e. cors and xhr poll error

Answer (score 0):

seems like you have a typo

```
const ENDPOINT='http://localhost:4002';
```

Comment: Its giving me the same error, even if I do, 'localhost:4002' instead of 'hlocalhost:4002'

Comment: @sheetal - You should be passing `http://localhost:4002`.  `io()` wants an actual URL, not just a hostname.